# adding newline in string concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `textarea` and I do `console.log($("textarea").val())`, the result can be

```
abc

123
```

And I have an input, i want to concate the value with the value of textarea, like this

```
input_value

abc

123
```

I tried `<br>` but the br will appear which is not I want. How to make newline in concatenation? use `\n`?

Comment: Did you try `\n`? what happened?

Comment: You ask for `\n` but didn't try it? It's workine fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\n` instead of `<br>`. Like that:

```
console.log($("input").val() + '\n' + $("textarea").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
alert('abe \n' + 123);
```

\n Seems to do the trick for you.

Further Reading:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_newline.asp